# Django send mail from docker container how to expose port

Tags: python, django, docker, email, django-q

The mail sending works fine without the docker container. I think I actually opened the SMTP Port. Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    <some postgres setup>
  api:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=api.settings.production
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "587:587"
      - "25:25"
    expose:
      - 587
      - 25
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
    entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
  mail:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py qcluster --settings=api.settings.production
    depends_on:
      - api
```

It doesn't work to send mails no matter if I send it as an async task with django q or directly with `django.core.mail.send_mail`

Here is my mail settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

I get an OSError `OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address`

Comment: You only need `ports:` to accept inbound connections – if you're _receiving_ messages via SMTP.  More than just the settings you've shown here, can you provide a [mcve] with enough code to actually demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I don't need to receive messages, so I don't need 587 and 25 under `ports`? it's not easy to provide a code example, but I'm basically just calling the send_mail method from django.core.mail

Comment: Yes, you don't need 25 and 587 in `ports`. This is only for port forwarding. Try removing these and it might be everything you have to do to solve this.

Comment: unfortunately I get the same error after removing the ports

Comment: Double check if you need to disable 2-Step-Authentication in your gmail account for that email address. Or add it as an app : check it here https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1 and go down to app passwords

Comment: it is added as an app

Comment: when I run the code without docker I get `TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out`

Comment: found the problem, the port is blocked by my wifi. No need to expose the ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the port was blocked by my wifi.